# SSIS error printing a variable value in a C# script

Tags: sql, ssis, package, etl, ssis-2012

I'm trying to create a sample about how to catch the row count result in a variable within SSIS package and then just print the value using a simple script task.

So, first at all, I create a variable as Int32 where I'm going to store the row count result set and then I just pass through the count catch the value in a SSIS operation row count.

[image]

Then, in my Script task, I pass the variable as ReadOnly.

[image]

And finally, I type the code in the public void method to show up the current variable value.

```
public void Main()
        {
            // TODO: Add your code here
            string result = null;
            result = (string)Dts.Variables["qty"].Value;
            MessageBox.Show("The current value of the SSIS global variable 'TestVariable' is '" + result);
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }
```

**Issues**

In the image below you will see my current error in the show-up operation and also I realize that my current variable value is 0. Seems like the row count it is not getting the right value.

[image]

So guys, could you please give me a kind of guidance in order to succeded my requirement. thanks so much

Comment: i can't see images, but i have a suggestion. Add a breakpoint before starting script task. And look at the value of qty in locals.

Answer (score 0):

SSIS usually doesn't like you performing GUI operations (such as showing a MessageBox) during processing. There are functions to display this information in the Progress Window. Have a look at componentMetaData.FireInformation().